# how to use routerLink when using multi children?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

this is AdminRouting

```
    path: 'adminHome',
    component: adminHomeComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: HomeComponent,

        },
        {
            path: 'home',
            component: HomeComponent,

        },
        {
            path: 'users',
            component: UserListComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    component: HUComponent
                },
                {
                    path: ':id',
                    component: EntrepriseListComponent,
                    children: [
                        {
                            path: '',
                            component: HyComponent

                        },
                        {
                            path: ':id',
                            component: ListLaucauxComponent
                        },
                    ]
                }

            ]
        },
    ]
  },
```

I want to get List LocauxComponent By clicking on id of the enterprise in order to get this URL localhost:3000/adminHome/users/{{id_user}}/{{id_entreprise}}
I try with
`[routerLink]="['/adminHome/users/:id',x.id]"`
but i get another URL something like 
http://localhost:3000/adminHome/users/%3Aid/58e35bdeaf314301ec86c249

Comment: Whats wrong in this URL?

Comment: i get a nullPointerException on the back-end server

Comment: Can you check if you are getting the data with correct url by doing manual entry on browser?

Comment: yes it works and on the browsers it show what i want to get but on the console there is this errors :GET http://localhost:1616/entreprises/user/:id 500 () && EXCEPTION: Observable_1.Observable.throw is not a function &&ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:

Comment: and this too :TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.throw is not a function
    at CatchSubscriber.EntrepriseService.handleError [as selector] (entreprise.service.ts:44)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catch.ts:55)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.ts:139)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.ts:109)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.umd.js:1185)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:367)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.umd.js:3971)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:6)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:166)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is wrong. When using the `[routerLink]` you don't need to specift the `:id` the same as you dont need to do that with a path variable, it is defined as a placeholder to put the id.

The `[routerLink]` should look something like the following:

```
[routerLink]="['/adminHome/users', x.id]"
```

**EDIT**

In order to build the `[routerLink]` with more paramaters do the following:

```
[routerLink]="['/adminHome/users', param1, param2...]"
```

That will result in : `/adminHome/users/1/2` if `param1=1` and `param2=2`

Comment: but [routerLink]="['/adminHome/users', x.id]" will call EntrepriseListComponent as you can see on the routing.ts . the problem that it works like i want and  there is a null pointer exception on the server because of the change of id to %3Aid on the url . and when i change manually %3Aid By the right id there is no null pointer exception  and i can't find solution how to kept url like this localhost:3000/adminHome/users/{{id_user}}/{{id_entreprise}}

Comment: so it should be `[routerLink]="['/adminHome/users', x.id, param2]"` when building the link you cannot put `/:id` as it will just send it as plain text (`%3A` is the URL encoded version of `:`). routerLink will automaticaly build the URL for you if you do it right, the means giving the base URL as the first parameter as a String continuing with each param as needed like the following: `[routerLink]="['/adminHome/users', param1, param2, param3....]"`

Comment: it would be [routerLink]="['/adminHome/users', param2, x.id]" . and what should i put in params2 in order to remplace parms2 by {{id_user}} and how can i recupererate {{id_user}} and replace it into [routerLink] . i try with grab this id in the ngOnInit() and replace it like this "['/adminHome/users', {{id}}, x.id]"  but this syntax is not allowed

Comment: you need to use parameters from your component.ts file. if the name of the parameter is `id` you dont need `{{ }}` when injecting the parameter in `[routerLink]`. It work like any other angular directive. so it will probably be something like: `"['/adminHome/users', id, x.id]"` if `id` and `x.id` are configured as parameters in your component.